# Frobenius Method with Reduction of Order for a second solution.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$x(x-1)y''+3xy'+y=0$$

My attempt to solve is as follows:

$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}$$
$$-a_0(r)(r-1)x^{r-1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n(n+r)(n+r-1)-a_{n+1}(n+r+1)(n+r)+3a_n(n+r)+a_n)x^{n+r}=0$$

Using the indicial equation I obtained

$$r=0,1$$

Then for r=1

$$a_{n+1}=a_n\frac{n+2}{n+1}$$
$$y(x)=a_0(x+2x^2+3x^3+4x^4+\cdots)$$
$$y(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$

I then proceeded to use reduction of order to obtain a second solution, however the differentiation gets rather messy. As I understand it, assuming a solution of the form $y_2(x)=y(x)v(x)$ and substituting into the ODE, the $v(x)$ term should vanish and allow you to solve. However, I was not able to do this. The solution I obtained did not work, I tried keeping the solution in series form also but to no avail. Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Slightly quicker is to use the [Wronskian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations).  Let $y_1=x(1-x)^{-2}$, $y_2$ be linearly independent solutions of $x(x-1)y''+3xy'+y=0$.  The Wronskian $W=W[y_1,y_2]=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$ satisfies
$$
x(x-1)W'+3xW=0
$$
so $W=C\cdot(1-x)^{-3}$.  Hence we may take $C=1$ and thus
$$
\left(\frac{y_2}{y_1}\right)'=\frac{y_1y_2'-y_1'y_2}{y_1^2}=\frac{W}{y_1^2}
$$
*et cetera*.

---

**Addendum** With $y=y_1v$, we calculate
$$
y'=y_1'v+y_1v',\quad y''=y_1''v+y_1v''+2y_1'v'
$$
and hence substituting gives
$$\require{color}\require{cancel}
0=x(x-1)(\cancel{\color{red}y_1''v}+y_1v''+2y_1'v')+3x(\cancel{\color{red}y_1'v}+y_1v')+\cancel{\color{red}y_1v}
$$
i.e.,
$$
x(1-x)v''=(x-2)v'
$$
a first order differential equation for $v'$.

Comment: Solving for $W$ using the integrating factor method, I am left with $\frac{c}{(x-1)^3}$?

Comment: Huh?  Your $c$ and my $C$ differs by an irrelevant minus sign.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I solved the problem using the method you outlined. However, I still am not sure why reduction of order did not work, if you have an explanation or an area where I made an error that would be brilliant.

Comment: This is reduction of order.  $y_2/y_1$ is your $v$, we just bypass most of the messy calculations to get $v'=f(x)$ by appealing to properties of Wronskian.

Comment: So does the minus sign I omitted affect the solution? I computed both and I am left with a $\pm y_2(x)$, does this mean there are 3 solutions to the ODE?

Comment: No,  Remember this is a linear differential equations, the general solution is $y=\lambda y_1+\mu y_2$ and we are free to choose $y_2$ among all solutions that is not a constant multiple of $y_1$.